# Cloudfront facts using Ansible

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, amazon-cloudfront

I need to retrieve the DNS name of my Cloudfront instance (eg. 1234567890abcd.cloudfront.net) and was wondering if there is a quick way to get this in Ansible without resorting to the AWS CLI.

From gleaming the Extra Modules source it would appear there is not a module for this. How are other people getting this attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either write your own module or you can write a filter plugin in a few lines and accomplish the same thing.

Example of writing a filter in Ansible. Lets name this file aws.py in your filter_plugins/aws.py

```
import boto3
import botocore
from ansible import errors

def get_cloudfront_dns(region, dist_id):
""" Return the dns name of the cloudfront distribution id.
Args:
    region (str): The AWS region.
    dist_id (str): distribution id

Basic Usage:
    >>> get_cloudfront_dns('us-west-2', 'E123456LHXOD5FK')
    '1234567890abcd.cloudfront.net'
"""
client = boto3.client('cloudfront', region)
domain_name = None
try:
    domain_name = (
        client
        .get_distribution(Id=dist_id)['Distribution']['DomainName']
    )
except Exception as e:
    if isinstance(e, botocore.exceptions.ClientError):
        raise e
    else:
        raise errors.AnsibleFilterError(
            'Could not retreive the dns name for CloudFront Dist ID {0}: {1}'.format(dist_id, str(e))
        )
return domain_name

class FilterModule(object):
    ''' Ansible core jinja2 filters '''
    def filters(self):
        return {'get_cloudfront_dns': get_cloudfront_dns,}
```

In order to use this plugin, you just need to call it.

`dns_entry: "{{ 'us-west-2' | get_cloudfront_dns('123434JHJHJH') }}"`

Keep in mind, you will need boto3 and botocore installed, in order to use this this plugin.

I have a bunch of examples located in my repo [linuxdynasty ld-ansible-filters repo](https://github.com/linuxdynasty/ld-ansible-filter-plugins/blob/master/aws.py)

Comment: Thanks. I was hoping there was an easier way but creating a module may have to do.

Comment: In my opinion, creating a plugin is simpler for get requests like this. Unless you want to have a bunch of options. Than a module would be the best route.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing a module for this ([cloudfront_facts.py](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/pull/19727)) that has been accepted into Ansible 2.3.0.